# R Using an array to subset a table

Tags: r, loops

I've just created 10 variables in a loop using the assign function:

```
#Original.data.frame is a 10X5 data frame.
#table is a table of the combinations of Col.nums where r=2
Col.nums<- c(1:5)
 for(i in 1:ncol(data.frame)){
  name<- paste("Name.object.",i, sep = "")
  Boolean<- Col.nums %in% table[,i]
  assign(name,expand.grid(Original.data.frame[Boolean]))      
}
```

I now want to add creating another object (Name.object.total.i) where i is each iteration.

My question is: is there a way of indexing the name in each iteration to be able to run the rowSums function on it?

---

EDIT:
Basically I want to add:

```
name$row.sums<- rowSum(name[1:2])
```

To the end of that loop but have name be replaced by the content of name (as defined in the first line of the loop).

To visualise,the above loop produces 10 objects, each a combination of the subset of our 10x5 data frame. An example subset:

```
           Cost.1             Cost.2
1          9104.014           26118.75
2         10901.258           26118.75
3         11952.579           26118.75
4         12698.503           26118.75
5         13277.086           26118.75
6         13749.823           26118.75
7         14149.517           26118.75
```

The output I expect is the 10 tables as above with an extra column with the sum of the first two rows. Hope that makes it clearer!

Comment: Actually I deleted my post when rereading your post. I have no idea what you want, but it was not what I first thought. Better post some example data and what you expect as output.

Comment: Tried again. Still not sure I understand the task.

Comment: I've managed to find a different way of getting to my result. Apologies for not explaining it very well it's quite confusing even for me. I did learn about sprintf which may come in handy somewhere else. Cheers!

Comment: Well, did my post answer your question or not? I put work into this. If it did you should mark it as an answer. If not you should explain why that is the case. And if you want to drop it you should delete your post.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df <- data.frame(runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10))
names(df) <- sprintf("Col.%d",1:ncol(df))

colnums1 <- 1:3
colnums2 <- 4:5

df$cost.1 <- rowSums(df[,colnums1])
df$cost.2 <- rowSums(df[,colnums2])
```

Yields this:

```
> df
        Col.1     Col.2     Col.3     Col.4     Col.5    cost.1    cost.2
1  0.02554691 0.0348292 0.2318146 0.1358425 0.9466410 0.2921907 1.0824835
2  0.58132588 0.7876859 0.7916831 0.7257976 0.6240524 2.1606948 1.3498500
3  0.29918389 0.7582891 0.9910775 0.1924936 0.5182367 2.0485505 0.7107303
4  0.74494794 0.8174732 0.3195831 0.7058671 0.4047919 1.8820042 1.1106590
5  0.52303788 0.1036358 0.8388999 0.8052366 0.1312974 1.4655735 0.9365340
6  0.20339176 0.5381387 0.4736697 0.1199182 0.7620207 1.2152002 0.8819390
7  0.42020501 0.3035775 0.3269214 0.1702709 0.5577061 1.0507039 0.7279769
8  0.27012667 0.8610641 0.8194125 0.3870223 0.2208947 1.9506033 0.6079170
9  0.04770033 0.8950735 0.1927350 0.8565112 0.4924964 1.1355088 1.3490075
10 0.99183198 0.8061123 0.5915283 0.9464604 0.8511332 2.3894725 1.7975936
>
```